# How to make an empty createcontext in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, createcontext

I keep wanting to use a use cotext hook but i learned to use use context by putting an empty {} in the create context thing. But it is giving me errors. Not assignable to {} and type any not available.

```
import React from "react";

type data = {
    state?: any;
};

const state = 1;
export const BasicContext = React.createContext<data>(state);
```

this gave an error

> Type '1' has no properties in common with type 'data'.(2559)

How do i fix it? It is weird?

Comment: There's a syntax error in your post, and `React` is not defined. And when I do correct these, assuming they are typos, I get completely unrelated errors: https://tsplay.dev/WkDL2w

Comment: almost 
import React from "react";
import { createContext } from "react";

type data={
    state?: any;
}

const state = 1;
export const BasicContext = React.createContext<data>(state)

this still gives

Comment: Type '1' has no properties in common with type 'data'.ts(2559)

Comment: Yeah... that is not the error shown in your post... Can you update your post to correct these errors?

Comment: To fix it, just give it the right type. It expects an object with a `state` property, but you're giving it a number. https://tsplay.dev/WvqvRm

Comment: like this is still gives error 
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

type data = {
    state?: any;
};

const [open,setOpen] = useState(false)
export const BasicContext = React.createContext<data>(open);

Comment: sory formatting hold on

Comment: Did you read my last comment and click on the playground link?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzgFcBnJAZRhRiTgF85tcBIuhhly5GAE8w3ACacUcALx1ycdXCYcuAfgBccFADtJFHhXJoIRrXADaEGUYA0LGAHknAXWWMW7TiQACkwUABsWAEpyJAAPangrG3gAIRQmYDQAYWsuWPgVZBEAOjRhLhyjPJgAHnkOAD4gxyQjSIsgA

Comment: Again, give it the correct type: https://tsplay.dev/WyqadW

Comment: can you send as answer so i can mark it @vr

Answer (score 0):

You're giving it the wrong type. Since you used `createContext<data>`, it expects an initial value with the type `data`. Because `data` is an object type, and you passed a number, TypeScript throws an error.

You can wrap your state in brackets taking advantage of [property initializer shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) to easily create an object that matches the `data` type:

```
const state = 1;
export const BasicContext = React.createContext<data>({ state });
//                 same as passing { state: state } - ~~~~~~~~~
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgBMUYU4BeOAb3Ll7gGcWMJAH4AXHBQA7ahQC+FcmghTBAofQ4BGCkgAekWHGWr4AIRT9gaAMIrhe+B2ToYAOjRFmSO1IcwAHiYWAD4ACk51bzg5AEoKIA)